# expand text field value box in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: user-interface, phpmyadmin, field

When I'm in phpmyadmin and try to Change the values within a row, the Value field is too small to show the entire value for some columns. I want to be able to see the entire box, not have to hit the right/left arrow key to cycle through it. I know some pages have the <-T-> button (Expand All Fields) but I can't find it in the options. Or the SQL result page has the Options --> show Full Text Radio Button. Is there a way to 'stretch' out the field?

**image of what I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: Is this not a proper place to ask this? I will delete this question if it shouldn't be here.

Comment: Please show us the column's definition and tell us which phpMyAdmin version.

Comment: Version information: 3.4.11.1  
I'm not sure how to check the columns' definition.

Comment: Via the Structure page for this table.

Comment: I can't seem to find a 'Drag Here To Expand' hover option, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHPMyAdmin, go to Home, under "Appearance Settings" click "More settings".  Click "Features", then click "Text fields". Change "Maximum size for input field" to something bigger, like 200.

This worked for me:

[image: screenshot]

https://yourhostname/phpmyadmin/doc/html/config.html#cfg_MaxSizeForInputField

http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#text-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [GreaseMonkey extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) on firefox and use this script to increase the size of all inputs of size 40 (was the max for me) to 1000px.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Textfield insertion width increase
// @namespace   localhost
// @description Increased width of textfield
// @include     http://your_ip_address/phpmyadmin/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$('input[size=40]').width(1000);
```